# 50 amp stove? and it appears to be gas

Tags: stove

My buddy wants me to hook up his stove, but it has a 50 amp cord at the bottom. Why does a gas stove need a 50 amp cord. My stove just has a plug for a 110 volts. His stove is not electric, I'm a little confused, or should I say unlearned.

Comment: Unplug the stove but leave the gas hooked up.  What still works? What breaks?

Comment: a guess: manufacturer provided consumers with the most likely connector to be found behind a stove; it _will_ work, right? check the label for the actual power consumption.

Answer (score 4):

The stove may be one of the more modern types known as having "dual fuel". I have one of those and the cook top burners above are using natural gas while the oven operates on electricity. In fact even the oven has two operating modes selectable between static heat generation and convection with the hot air being moved around.

As such the stove unit has a 50A electrical hookup and a gas line hookup.

Answer (score 0):

[The earlier-posted answer](/a/117897) wisely suggests your buddy may have a gas stovetop but an electric oven. If both are gas, perhaps the cord is for an electric ignition. Typically that draws much fewer amps than fifty, but maybe that's what the cord is for.

Comment: If you came across a gas-only oven (which used electricity only for ignition and oven light) and it was plugged into a 50A connector, it means the last guy made a serious wiring mistake. Far worse if the connector is NEMA 10, because then the oven chassis is grounded to neutral, and an upstream problem with the neutral wire could electrify the oven chassis at 120V right while you're touching it.  Better to reconfigure those fat wires to feed a 120V/20A breaker and receptacle.